# Visual Studio 2017 References

Tags: reference, visual-studio-2017, .net-framework-version

Why are System dlls at version 4.0.0.0 when the .Net Framework of is 4.7.1?

[Link to screenshot of VS project references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq7PI.png)

Comment: Because the System DLLs are still at version 4.0.0.0.

Comment: Thanks. I was following Microsoft's best practices to insure TLS1.2 in a web service proj. The recommendation by ms was to update .net framework to 4.7 or greater. The proj. was at 4.5. But after doing the update, that's when I checked the DLLs and got worried the site was still using the previous .net framework.